# SvelteKit dev server doesn't start

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte

I want to try out the new SvelteKit replacement for Sapper, but I'm not able to start a dev server.

I ran:

```
npm init svelte@next
npm install
npm run dev -- --open
```

Error:

```
(node:16570) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: .../Desktop/Programming/Web Development/Svelte/Demo-app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/index4.js:262
        #map;
        ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (../Desktop/Programming/Web Development/Svelte/Demo-app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/index.js:13:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
(node:16570) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:16570) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I haven't touched the generated code.

I know these kinds of errors pop when it's unable to open a new browser tab with the server started, but I have no idea how to fix it here.

- Node Version: v10.19.0
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, 64-bit
- Browser: Firefox 83.0 (64-bit)
- Proxy: Burp Suite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess `#map` is some [`private class field`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields) that is supported starting from node 12.

You can try using node 12 or a newer version.

Comment: it's true what you say. as a side note, we can check this looking at `package.json` for something like `"engines": {"node": ">= xxx"}`. In my case xxx is `12.17.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are trying to make a template and using the template syntax

```
{#map bla bla}
```

Then the error might just be that `map` is not supported and you might have to switch to [#each](https://svelte.dev/docs#each)

```
{#each expression as name}...{/each}
```

Comment: The error is pointing towards node_modules, I haven't started coding yet.